# What container allows both binary_search'ing and random deletion of elements?

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, stl, containers

I've been using `std::vector` but it has become unwieldy as the data it iterates through has grown and I would like to be able to filter out random elements when they become redundant. I have this behaviour elsewhere with `std::list` but can't get `binary_search` to play nice with that.

Is there some code I could utilize to get `binary_search` to work again or must I employ still more elaborate containers and syntax?

```
        if(binary_search(iter + 1, myLines.end(), line)) {
            firstFound.assign(line);
            if (numFinds++) break;
        }
```

Comment: What about a `std::deque`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6455647/3807729 (A `deque` is like a `vector` that is split up into *chunks* or a linked list of `vectors`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::set`'s lookup is `O(log(N))`, exactly as for `binary_search`, and the deletion is `O(1)` provided you have an iterator, and `O(log(N))` if you don't (lookup + deletion). Although the set will store the elements sorted, that must be OK for you, since `binary_search` also works only for sorted ranges.

Comment: Yes, I have sorted data, it's also unique too, if that matters, though I had forgotten that detail. Thanks, seems more intuitive than map.

Comment: @John: If you ever need non-unique data, there's `multiset`

Comment: N.B. you can't use `std::binary_search()` with `std::set` iterators because they are not RandomAccessIterators, but you can use `std::set::find()` and other members such as `std::set::count()` and `std::set::lower_bound()` which are implemented as binary searches of the container.

Comment: I abandoned most of these new containers and went back to using `std::vector` and instead of deleting elements (which I didn't have the right `iterator` to do when using a `set`) I put invalidated entries into a `set` so they could be easily ignored in future iteration. Pleased to learn yet another standard container, much nicer than `map`s. Two years ago I'd have been all for mocking up my own class with `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a [binary search tree (BST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

It trivially allows binary searching (it's in the name after all), and deletion is relatively straightforward.

Many kinds of binary search trees exist. Some common ones :

- [**simple BST**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) : large spread between worst and best case search performance, depending on the specific usage (inserting and deleting) of the BST. The higher the tree, the worse the performance.
- [**self-balancing BST**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) : on every insert/delete, nodes are shifted around if needed to keep the tree height minimal, and hence the search performance optimal. This comes at the cost of added overhead (which can become prohibitively high) when inserting and deleting.
- [**red-black tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) : a kind of self-balancing BST that doesn't always strive for the optimal height, but is still good enough to keep lookups O(log n). It performs very consistently for a wide range of use cases (ie. has good general purpose performance), which is why it was picked for the implementation of `std::set` (see [Armen Tsirunyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26362681/822669)).
- [**splay tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) : BST that keeps recently accessed items at the top of the tree where they can be accessed the fastest. It is not self-balancing, so the height is not kept minimal. This kind of tree is very useful when recently accessed data is likely to be accessed again soon.
- [**treap**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) : BST that uses random priorities are assigned to items, in order to probably (ie. using probability theory) keep the height of the tree close to minimal. It doesn't guarantee an optimal search performance, but in practice it usually does, and this without the added overhead of self-balancing or similar re-organizing algorithms.

Which of these is best for you, will depend on your specific use case.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suppose the reason was that a BST is already nicely wrapped in std::map and std::set, so no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Anyway, here's a +1 to compensate

Comment: to clarify why I thought it worth adding this answer : red-black trees are indeed a kind of self-balancing binary search tree, and so using `std::set` is an option (as per @ArmenTsirunyan's answer). But it has more overhead than a normal BST (mainly due to the re-balancing), which might not be desirable. You also don't need to roll your own - existing implementations are readily available (albeit not as part of the standard library).

Comment: The error in your comment is that the lookup in a normal BST is not O(LogN), but it is rather O(H), where H is the height of the tree. In the worst case, H can be N, making lookup linear!

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan : that is true, but if my understanding of the OP's description (some "random" deletes, no mention of adding) is correct, the risk of that worst case is pretty minimal. I do agree with you that `std::set` is probably the better idea (if only because it's the easiest), but if the use case allows for it, and performance is a concern, a simple BST is an alternative. I should probably expand on my answer to make all of this more clear.